# Cannot push my application in CloudFoundry.com

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am successfully logged into [CloudFoundry](http://api.CloudFoundry.com) but when I try to push my application, it fails with the following error:

**Error 702: External URIs are not enabled for this account**

Details:

```
$ vmc push
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]: y
Application Name: alcor
Detected a Java SpringSource Spring Application, is this correct? [Yn]: 
Application Deployed URL [alcor.CloudFoundry.com]: 
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [512M]: 
How many instances? [1]: 
Bind existing services to 'alcor'? [yN]: y
1: mysql-js
Which one?: 1
Create services to bind to 'alcor'? [yN]: 
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]: 
Creating Application: Error 702: External URIs are not enabled for this account
```

Any idea? Should I register a subdomain? Should I change my account?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check which vmc version are you using?

```
vmc -v
```

Seems the cloud foundry subdomain should be all in lower case. In your case it is alcor.CloudFoundry.com which should be alcor.cloudfoundry.com. If possible you might want to upgrade to the latest version and retry.

The beta version of Cloud Foundry does not support external URL. But it is on the roadmap to support this feature when it goes GA. You can wait until then and try it out if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks,
It works when using only lowercase as in alcor.cloudfoundry.com

Answer (score 0):

I would say try it again this time with another name other than alcor. CloudFoundry.com restrict some URIs and this might be one of them.

Comment: Thanks,
It works when using lower case as in alcor.cloudfoundry.com
vmc version: 0.3.18